# Storing numbers with multiple decimal points in Rails db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails app, I need to add a field for software version number, e.g., 3.2.1

What is the appropriate datatype for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a String.

Version numbers are rarely numbers and typically each section will have a specific meaning, even if it is only significant to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the Rails (ActiveRecord migration) datatypes, may be this helps

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html